# React Native: How to refresh a previous screen WITHOUT navigating to it?

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm having a simple issue where I'm transitioning between 3 separate screens:

```
SCREEN A --> SCREEN B --> SCREEN C
```

When I'm at screen C and I save something, I can navigate back to Screen B and refresh it. That's no issue.

The problem I'm having is Screen A has a count of items from Screen B.
So when I save from Screen C, the list for Screen B gets updated but not the count in Screen A.

All of the solutions I'm seeing are using navigation and passing a parameter but I don't want to navigate to that screen in this circumstance. How would I go about updating Screen A without having to navigate to it?

Comment: Consider using context or any type of global state management

Comment: either you need to use global state or `useFocusEffect` to refetch when screen is focus again.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Comment: @IanVasco I ended creating a singleton to manage refreshing but it's not working reliably enough. @ucup I might give the singleton approach a shot with `useFocusEffect` thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use a global state using Redux or any other state management tool or pass in a callback method when navigating from screen A to screen B to screen C like so

```js
// Screen A
const [data, setData] = useState();
navigation.navigate('Screen B': {callback: (data) => setData(data)}));

// Screen B
const [data, setData] = useState();
navigation.navigate('Screen C', {callback: (data) => setData(data)}));

const onGoBackPress = () => {
navigation.goBack();
route.params.callback(data)
}
 
// Screen C 
const data = {'some data from screen c'};

const onGoBackPress = () => {
navigation.goBack();
route.params.callback(data);
}
```

Comment: This was actually the solution I was looking for! The only issue with this is on an android device, they can hit the back button on the phone instead of the one we put on the view. Is there a way to handle both cases?

Comment: You may employ React Lifecycle methods to handle this i.e. componentWillUnmount or useEffect with return.

 `useEffect(() => {return () => {route.params.callback()}}, []);`